# Comma separated value within double quote

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a data file separated by comma, data enclosed by `""`:

```
$ head file.txt
"HD","Sep 13 2016 1:05AM","0001"
"DT","273093045","192534"
 "DT","273097637","192534" ..
```

I want to get the 3rd column value (`0001`) to be assigned to my variable.

I tried

```
FILE_VER=`cat file.txt | awk -F',' '{if ($1 == "HD") print $3}'`
```

I don't get any value assigned to `FILE_VER`. Please help me with correct syntax.

Comment: can you clarify your expected output? you say `0001` but awk script you tried would give `"0001"`... you had to include the quotes while comparing... `awk -F',' '{if ($1 == "\"HD\"") print $3}' file.txt` or to match part of string, `awk -F',' '{if ($1 ~ /HD/) print $3}' file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Simply removing the quotes should be good enough:

```
foo=$(awk -F, '$1=="\"HD\""{gsub(/"/,"",$3);print $3}' file)
```

Comment: Thank you to both hek2mgl and @Jean-François Fabre

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` version:

```
awk -F'"' '$2 == "HD"{print $6}' file
```

Comment: That's dangerous. It will break as soon as the csv contains a field like `"foo\"bar"`. The delimiter here is the `,` and that should be used.

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes i will break, but so would the removal of all `"` as the data would be incomplete. Both of these might not be a problem here though. If one want to be sure and cater edge cases, then a real csv parser should be used.

Comment: It works fine, but dont know when it will break. Going with the option by hek2mgl

Comment: To be fair, as andlrc pointed out, my solution is as stable as this. Both work only if the data fields itself can't contain the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file to substitute the comma and quotes to tab:

```
tr -s '\"," "\t' < filename | awk '{print $3}'
```

Maybe there is a solution using only awk, but this works just fine!

Comment: Congratulations you won the [useless use of cat award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)! (to name just one of the problems with your answer)

Comment: I think @hek2mgl answered  at the same time! =P

Comment: Yes, I now you don't need to use cat... it's just that I'm used to... Actually my first 3 commands can be just one... I'm changing that. But I think the answer with awk is what he was looking for!

Comment: Looks better now, but the `tr` command is still not working properly. I guess you want `tr -d  '"' < filename | awk '$1 == "HD" {print $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is the most optimal way but works:

```
FILE_VER=$(awk -F',' '$1 == "\"HD\"" {gsub("\"","",$3); print $3}' file.txt)
```

1. test for `HD` between quotes
2. remove quotes before printing result